# Query inside of another query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've searched and found ways to do queries inside queries, but I have not found the right answer.

What I am trying to do is to fetch comments from the table called `users_profiles_comments` and by doing that I will get the field of `'.$member["author"].'`. Then I want to show who made the comment with their rank and a display picture.

But because there is no user details stored in the comments table because its for comments, I need to create a query inside of my query result where I can have this:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $member['author'] ORDER BY `id` ASC"
```

The '.$member["author"].' value comes from the main query but I need it so it can find fields in my users table.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_profiles_comments WHERE postid = '1' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$users = $stm->fetchAll();

foreach ($users as $row) {
    print '

    <img src="'.$member["profilepic"].'" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;" width="80px" height="85pxm">

    <h4>'. $row["author"] .'
                    <small>'. $row["date"] .'</small>
                </h4>
                <p>'. $row["content"] .'</p><hr> </a></li>';
}
echo '
</div>  


  ';
```

I hope you understand.

Edit:
The database.

users Table
http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/4387/qyjl.png

users_profiles_comments table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JKi2.png

Comment: We need schema to give the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select member name in SQL statement. You can try this query, this query will bring all the information from two table if  `users.username` = `users_profiles_comments.author`

**WAY 1:**

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM
(
      SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '.$member["author"].' ORDER BY `id` ASC
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
      SELECT * FROM users_profiles_comments WHERE postid = '1' ORDER BY `id` ASC
) AS t2
ON t1.username = t2.author
```

Finally, do your `foreach` to print

`===================================================================`

**WAY 2:**

You can try this also-

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT profilepic FROM users WHERE users.username = users_profiles_comments.author) AS profilepic
FROM users_profiles_comments WHERE postid = '1' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

And print `profilepic` using `$row['profilepic']` in your `foreach loop`

`=====================================================================`

**WAY 3:**

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM
(
      SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid = '1'
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
      SELECT * FROM users
) AS t2

ON t1.author = t2.username
```

Comment: Does this do both queries? Like I still need to get information from users_profiles_comments.

Comment: please add the two `table structure` with your question... I mean fields as list not require all... but neccessary fields at-least

Comment: Would images do fine?

Comment: I think you can't add image

Comment: Just added links to the two images of both tables.

Comment: Did you see the database table images?

Comment: I added new query with my answer

Answer (score 2):

> But because there is no user details stored in the comments table because its for comments

This is good. You do not want to have your database information duplicated in both tables (de-normalized data) - there is no need.

Generally a **foreign key** is added to inverse side of the relationship. This would mean you have a `user_id` column within your `comments` table, allowing you to select the data in one query using a `JOIN`

```
SELECT comment.*, user.name AS comment_author
FROM comment
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = comment.user_id
WHERE user.id = 123
```

**Edit** - I flipped to `JOIN` to return comments rather than users, (as you said "to fetch comments") however both ways will work, it just depends which side of the relationship you are on.

**Edit 2**  To respond to your comment;

> How would I be able to show this on my PHP code on the result?

you can be more specific with the above query (not use `*`) and render it as follows :

```
$sql = "
  SELECT 
    comment.`date` as comment_date,
    comment.content, 
    user.name AS author_name, 
    user.profilepic as author_pic 
  FROM
    users_profiles_comments as comment
  INNER JOIN 
    user ON user.id = comment.user_id
  WHERE 
    comment.postid = 1
"; 
//...
$comments = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
  echo '<img src="' . $comment['author_pic'] . '"/>';
  echo '<h4>' . $comment['author_name'] . '<small>' . $comment['comment_date'] .'</small></h4>';
  echo '<p>' . $comment['content'] . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Also gives you the ability to `LEFT JOIN` if you wanted to retrieve say 'all users who've never commented' and so on; fk it ;)

Comment: How would I be able to show this on my PHP code on the result? So for example to be able to do  `'. $row["date"] .' ` and get information from both tables?

Comment: You just specify the columns you want to process in the select (don't use SELECT *), and use that column name. If there are columns with the same name on both tables then you can alias the column name. for example, SELECT user.fred, comment.fred as burt....

Comment: Could you make the values of this query the same as my values listed in my original post, so I understand it betteR? Thanks.

Comment: @user3219007 - Updated based on your comment and specific example

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you need to get information about the user from another table called user_profile_comments, based on the user id (correct me if wrong: :-)). Use a `left outer JOIN` to fetch data from another table, limited on user id.

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for more info.

Comment: How will I be able to show it on my php code result? Such as `'. $row["date"] .' `?

Comment: `$row['date']` is a result from a row column in the table. With a `JOIN`  you can use that row column to limit on another table. So you are fetching data from two tables with one query (that's what you want right?).